# SqlAlchemy and implicit join

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have a two tables in parent/child relationship, relations are specified on model level.
Now, If I want to use select in which I am selecting some fields from parent and some from child table, I would have expected that join condition like `Parent.id == Child.parent_id` is automatically added.
For example if I execute `select([Parent, Child])` I would have expected the following sql:

```
SELECT parents.id, parents.name, children.id AS id_1, children.parent_id, children.name AS name_1 
FROM parents, children
WHERE parrents.id = children.parent_id
```

Instead of `Parent.id == Child.parent_id`, this would surely work `select([Parent, Child]).join(Child, Parent.id == Child.parent_id)` but I wander why I have to specify already specified relation?

Am I expecting to much?

Here is the code I have used for the experiment:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, select, Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

# Define parent and child models
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parents'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    children = relationship('Child', back_populates='parent')

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'children'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parents.id'))
    name = Column(String)
    parent = relationship('Parent', back_populates='children')

# Create an engine and session
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

# Create tables
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

# Create parent and child objects
parent = Parent(name='John Doe')
child = Child(name='Jane Doe', parent=parent)

# Add objects to the session
session.add(parent)
session.add(child)
session.commit()

# Perform a query with automatic join
stmt = select([Parent, Child])

print(stmt.compile(compile_kwargs={'literal_binds': True}))
```

Output:

```
SELECT parents.id, parents.name, children.id AS id_1, children.parent_id, children.name AS name_1 
FROM parents, children
SAWarning: SELECT statement has a cartesian product between FROM element(s) "parents" and FROM element "children".  Apply join condition(s) between each element to resolve.
```

Comment: Not sure what is the question, but the closest query would be something like `stmt = select([Parent, Child]).select_from(Parent).join(Child)` and it would use automatically relationship condition.

Comment: My question is if I specified relation between Parent and Child in the model and if I am selecting from both of these tables, how come that I have to specify select_from(Parent).join(Child). 
According to model, whenever I am selecting from both of these tables relation should be automatically applied.

Why do I need relation specified in the model?
I could always select(Parent, Child).join(Child, Child.parent_id== Parend.id).

Comment: In the case of selecting from two tables it'd be unclear if you want a FROM clause with comma-separated table names or if you want a FROM clause with JOIN clause. If there is a relationship between tables, then user may still want a Cartesian product query. IMO It'd be difficult to use the same syntax for different types of queries, by specifying select_from/join_from/join it's resolved

Comment: Having FROM clause with comma-separated table names or JOIN clause is irrelevant implementation detail (it is just how select looks not how it behaves). Cartesian product is a special case query rarely used (compared to non Cartesian selects).
Maybe I just have a different idea how sqlalchemy should work.
If it works as it is, and nobody complains, it is probably the best way.
Anyway, @inf581 thank you very much for your explanations.
Using sqlalchemy I always had an impression that I am doing something wrong, but you cleared things out to me.
Thanks.